# How to update a Cosmos DB item from a Node JS app

Tags: node.js, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, put

I have a Cosmos Document DB with many items in it and I'd like to update a single item.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
const { resources: updatedItem } = await container.item(existingType).replace(newItem)
```

But get this error:

```
Illegal characters ['/', '\', '?', '#'] cannot be used in resourceId
```

Upon further research it's because the _rid is being read from the existingType and contains patterns like `AAAAA==/`

What is the best practice for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/cosmos/item?view=azure-node-latest#read_T__RequestOptions_)

> Read the item's definition. Any provided type, T, is not necessarily
> enforced by the SDK. You may get more or less properties and it's up
> to your logic to enforce it. If the type, T, is a class, it won't pass
> typeof comparisons, because it won't have a match prototype. It's
> recommended to only use interfaces.
>
> There is no set schema for JSON items. They may contain any number of
> custom properties.

You can create entity class so that you can remove system properties.